# What are normal landing separation minima?

Tags: air-traffic-control, separation, wake-turbulence

As far as I know we have separation minima of 10 minutes in horizontal flight, so do we have any equivalent separation minima for landing? If so, how it is possible to land two aircraft in a very short time, like 40 seconds? And doesn't this create wake vortices?

Comment: An air traffic controller won't land a Cessna 172 behind an Airbus A380 with a 40 second separation, usually they like to land the same class in short intervals to minimize wake turbulence issues. When changing weight classes, they will space them out further to allow the wake turbulence to dissipate. Really the biggest concern is getting the landing aircraft off the runway before the one on approach needs to go around.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! You might want to check some of our existing questions about separation and wake turbulence: [here](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/24272/62), [here](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/26183/62), [here](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/25987/62), [here](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/17162/62) and the [separation](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/separation) and [wake-turbulence](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wake-turbulence) tags

Comment: (Posting a reply to your "answer" below here) Yes, its very possible. Especially considering Dubai has parallel runways they can provide separation since the 43 seconds is total landings, not for an individual runway.

Comment: This is pretty well answered at http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/26183/8730

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is no set time between aircraft recovery; just enough time for the aircraft type, approach speed, typical required ground rolls and time for the aircraft to taxi clear of the runway prior to the next arrival.  Usually for busy hubs in Class B airspace, spacing is kept to a minimum, sometimes even less than a minute between arriving flights.